# mvn test returns 0 tests run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit5

Trying to run mvn from the IntelliJ terminal and it is not running the tests? Like it runs but returns the following

When I run mvn test from the project directory's command line I get the following.....

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.308 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I read the following and it said that you should be sure your Maven is at 3.6.0 which mine is at 3.6.1

https://springframework.guru/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven/

[image]

Here is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>movieweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anyone know why this may be happening? I'm stumped.

Comment: How have you named your test class? Do you like to run your tests with JUnit Jupiter or TestNG?

Comment: My tests are named MovieApplicationTests.java and UserMoviesTests.java both are in the src/test/java/movieweb.movies package.  I had been running my tests in IntelliJ using  whatever tool it provides by default. Now that I am trying to get it to run on the command line so I can do CI/CD with Bitbucket, im getting these problems.

Comment: I'm using JUnit 5

Comment: As a first step I’d remove the dependency to testng and see what happens. My guess is that you’ve been using testng all the time without being aware of it.

Comment: You need to add JUnit dependency to your `pom.xml` (exclude JUnit provided by Intellij), resolve dependency errors and then it will work

Comment: Then remove testng dependency cause you are using TestNG instead of JUnit jupiter cause you don't have a dependency to it which means your class contains imports from `org.testng.` instead `org.junit.jupiter.api.*` instead...

Comment: Yep removing org.testing and replacing it with org.junit.jupiter broke my testing but showed me that the break was in needing to change the  Beforemethod which org.testing uses to BeforeEach which JUnit uses. 

Replaced that and ran mvn clean test and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set `MAVEN_HOME` in IntelliJ: File->Settings (or
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> under windows), then search for maven and set the "Maven home path" to your local maven installation.

This prevented the use of TestNG and my tests were executed. Don't know why TestNG was used before, I had no TestNG dependency in my `pom.xml`.